# Swift project with Cocoapods dependencies

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have the following cocoapods Podfile

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'Foo' do
        pod "SwiftyJSON", '~> 2.2.0'
        pod "Locksmith"
        pod "GoogleMaps"
        pod "RealmSwift"
end

target 'FooTests' do

end
```

I'm also using cocoapods 0.37.2. For some reason, when I try to run the app, it complains with the following error, when clearly I have specified that my project requires SwiftyJSON 2.2.0 or greater:

```
 Reason: Incompatible library version: Foo requires version 2.0.0 or later, but SwiftyJSON provides version 1.0.0
```

I have verified that there's no other dependencies on SwiftyJSON (using cocoapods-dependencies):

```
$pod dependencies

Dependencies
---
- GoogleMaps (1.10.1)
- Locksmith (1.2.2)
- Realm (0.93.2):
  - Realm/Headers (= 0.93.2)
- Realm/Headers (0.93.2)
- RealmSwift (0.93.2):
  - Realm (= 0.93.2)
- SwiftyJSON (2.2.0)
```

As you can see, no one is pulling SwiftyJSON 1.0.0. By the way, the reason I'm using cocoapods 0.37.2 is because of this bug when I tried to use 0.38.1:  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3890.

Have I missed anything here (regarding the SwiftyJSON version mismatch) ? I've tried cleaning the project, redoing pod install, etc without any luck..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well. This sounds crazy, but I just removed SwiftyJSON as a dep, upgraded cocoapods to 0.38.0, added SwiftyJSON again, and do pod install. Then re open my project. Everything looks good. I dont know whether it was because of the upgrade, or whether it is because of remove-and-add-again that fixed my problem. I've wasted about 3 hours today trying to fix this silly problem.

Comment: I'm having same issue, started today as well (post cocoapods 0.38.1 installation, and I've since downgraded to 0.37.2 and it's still happening)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me (and for you it seems), the following worked:

1. Remove guilty pods from podfile (in my case, `AFNetworking` and `AFNetworkActivityLogger`)
2. `pod install` to wipe them out
3. Upgrade (or downgrade if you're on 0.38.1) to cocoapods 0.38.0
4. Add pods back & `pod install`

Now I'm back in business... I believe 0.38.1 was responsible for getting me into this mess.

Comment: Yep. Thats what I did too. Uninstall the offending pods, uninstall cocoapods 0.38.1, install cocoapods 0.38.0, and reinstall the offending pods. Seems to be ok. Finger cross!

Comment: If anyone else keeps having the issues even after doing the above steps. I had to "Clean the Build folder". You can do that in Xcode with pressing alt and clicking on the menu on "Product" and then select "Clean Build Folder".